# javascript textarea character limit per line

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea with limited characters per line. Its function fine.

```
function limitRow(){
    var count = 1;
    var charsPerLine = row; // 30 characters  
    var maxLines = 20; 

    $('.AD_Text_textarea').keydown(function (e) {
        var v = $(this).val(),
        vl = v.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').length,
        lineCount = $(this).val().split("\n").length;

        if (parseInt(vl / count) >= charsPerLine) {
            if (lineCount >= maxLines) {
                return false;
            }
            $(this).val(v + "\n");
            count += 1;
        }
    });
}
```

My question is, if Iam going to line 1, after typing for example 4 rows text and type on for example cursor position 4 some text, then the line counter counts of the beginning and breaks the line after 60 characters and jumps on the end of line 4.
How can I resolve this problem? 
I hope, it was clear. (Iam sorry for my english)

Comment: In my opinion the best option is to forget about doing this in response to keystrokes, and do it on blur. That way you not only avoid the jumping problem, you allow for the user changing the text via the Edit menu or with the mouse. (By the way, your English is fine.)

Comment: Just change `$('.AD_Text_textarea').keydown()` to `$('.AD_Text_textarea').blur()` to follow @nnnnnn's [excellent] advice.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var count = 1;
    var charsPerLine = 30; // 30 characters  
    var maxLines = 2;
    $('.AD_Text_textarea').keydown(function (e) {
        var this_input = $(this);
        var value = this_input.val().split('\n');

        if (value.length < maxLines) {
            if (value[parseInt(value.length) - 1].toString().length > charsPerLine) {
                alert(value.length.toString());
                this_input.val(this_input.val() + '\n');
            }

        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```